# Human Motion tracking unity/android

Tags: android, unity, augmented-reality

I'm currently attempting to code an android app with AR elements. I want it to track a human going through exercises or such. I've looked into posenet and such, but was wondering if there was a way to track human movement in Unity. I've looked into the ARCore plugin for unity but it doesn't seem to have this. Arkit does seem to have this but it seems to only be able to be coded on iOS. Any ideas on what I could use?